# only one circle at center required

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I want only one circle at the center and not the circles surrounding it.And I do not want to change the current code (gradient-style).How can I achieve it??

```css
 
 #bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, yellow 99.9%, blue 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, yellow 50%, transparent 10%);
  background-position: 50% 100px, 50% 50%;  
  background-size:100% 15px, 100px 100px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `repeat-x`

```css
#bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, yellow 99.9%, blue 99.9%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, yellow 50%, transparent 10%);
  background-position: 50% 100px, 50% 50%;  
  background-size:100% 15px, 100px 100px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `repeat-x`

```
 #bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff; //type in your color between # and ;
  background-position: 50% 100px, 50% 50%;  
  background-size:0 15px, 100px 100px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```